# Get active month in calendar

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I want to get the month for the current active month in the calendar. For example, the current month (December 2012) includes (but does not show) Nov 26-30, which the `beforeShowDay` (date) function includes when looping in the 'date'. I want to get Dec '11' (0 based index) at the start but can't find how to get this.

Using `date.getMonth() + 1` doesn't work as it first gives me Novembers month number but I want Dec as that is the selected month in the calendar. I get Dec when I eventually get to in in the loop via 'date' but it's to late at that point.

Any ideas how to get this?

Comment: After the datepicker is instantiated, you can always use `$( ".selector" ).datepicker( "getDate" );` to get the currently selected date in the datepicker. Here's a [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/4MVK5/3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, this is what you are looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/kACfV/

```
// Initially, set current date as the active month.
var activeMonth = new Date().getMonth() + 1;

$(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({ 
        // This is run before beforeShowDay(date).
        onChangeMonthYear: function (year, month, inst) {
            activeMonth = month; // Store active month when month is changed.
        },
        beforeShowDay: function (date) {
            // Do your logic here with activeMonth.
            console.log(date + " > " + activeMonth);
            return [true, ""]
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Whoo! thats giving the number i need. sweet. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
var datePicker = $('#datepicker')
    datePicker.datepicker();
var date  =  datePicker.datepicker('getDate');

alert(date.getMonth())
```

Will output 11 (currently), although this will only work once the calendar date picker has been initialized, or shown. This means if you use the markup from the docs (the input field) you'll get no alert. A workaround for this could be setting the datepicker to a div surrounding the input, and triggering the datepicker show/hide when the input gains or loses focus.

Something on the lines of this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ugyvf/). It's a bit ugly but it should serve as a workaround for the input part:

```
var datePicker = $('#datepicker')
    datePicker.datepicker();
    datePicker.hide();

var date  =  datePicker.datepicker('getDate');

alert(date.getMonth());

$("[rel='#datepicker']").focus(function(){
   datePicker.show(); 
});

$("[rel='#datepicker']").blur(function(){
   datePicker.hide(); 
});
```

With the following HTML:

```
<input rel='#datepicker' type='text'/>
<div id='datepicker'></div>​
```

**Update**
You also ask how to get the month for the calendar on the `beforeShow` method. The way I think of it, you have two alternatives. Either you've set the month overriding the `defaultMonth` option or it will be the current month. If you've set it manually, you already have it, if you didn't it will probably just be the same number as in `new Date().getMonth()` (which in this case is, as you've probably guessed, 11)

Comment: Is there no way of getting this in the <code>beforeShowDay</code> function? I'm doing calculations to display the appropriate dates for selection and need this month value at this point? I get null if i use it there.

Comment: I keep getting an error on the getMonth() function? Says it's null? I 've placed this code just before the call to the #datepicker, is that the right place? Thanks.

Comment: The month, is a javascript feature, not just jquery ui. You create a new "Date object" hence the "new Date()" and to that object you call the method "getMonth()".